# What is the fastest way to build an alanine scanning library?

Tags: molecular-biology, protein-engineering

For interfacial studies, I would like to build an alanine scanning library for one of my proteins examining 20 sites. I will ultimately express the gene using *E.coli* cell-free protein synthesis. I already have the template gene which was originally built using PCR assembly. Now, what's the best way to build a scanning library?

Comment: do you mean, how do i decide which amino acids to include in the alanine scan or how do i create the library of alanine mutants?

Comment: @shigeta, definitely more "how".

Comment: http://www.genscript.com/alanine_scanning.html  genscript has some pages to help you reason through the design.  Myself I'm not sure, but it looks like it takes quite a lot of oligos to say the least...

Comment: Are you still interested in the answer of this question?

Comment: @GerganaVandova, not really but it might be of interest to the broader community.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest will change as time passes and better technologies are developed.

I think the fastest method existing at the moment is [Shotgun Mutagenesis](http://www.integralmolecular.com/mapping.php) (provided by Integral Molecular Inc).

This does not employ any new method of doing that. They just provide a set of plasmids, that has all the possible mutations. The set itself is generated by automated DNA synthesis.

So if you don't have a DNA synthesizer with you then simply order the kit from the company.